# What is the font used on PHP.net to show code?

Tags: font-identification

I noticed PHP.net changed the font used to show code examples.

Does someone know what this font is?

[image]

Updated: I've set my text editor to use **Fira Mono** as someone kindly pointed out but still why does it not look like the above?

[image]

Comment: Browsers can sometimes render fonts differently. What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: @Brendan It seems to me like he is trying to recreate the php.net syntax highlighting in his coding application... or partially anyways..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called **Fira Mono** [[Examples](http://mozilla.github.io/Fira/)] [[Download](http://www.carrois.com/fira-3-1/)]

> font-family: "Fira Mono","Source Code Pro",monospace;

[image: Fira Mono]

The letterspacing issue is also fixed with CSS:

> letter-spacing: -0.0625rem;
>       word-spacing: -0.125rem;

Comment: Hi, thanks for the font, can you check the question I updated and if you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to set such settings in Notepad++?

Comment: It's unlikely that a text editor can alter character spacing.